# vba: if cell contains whole word then

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am trying to write a piece of code to identify if string ***cell(2,5) = "This situation is bad"*** and ***cell(3,5) = "I would like to sit down"*** contains the word "sit".

Ideally cell(2,5) would return 0 and cell(3,5) would return 1.

Right now I have

```
for i = 2 to 3
  if LCase(cells(i,5)) like "*sit*" then
  cells(2,5) = 1
  end if
next i
```

The problem is cell(2,5) contains the word "situation", therefore "sit", my code would return 1 in this case.

I have also tried

```
if instr(1,cells(i,5),"sit") <> 0 then
cells(i,5) = 1
```

it gives the same inaccurate result

I wonder how can i have something returning to 1 if and only if the cell contains the whole word?

Comment: Check [InStr Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function)

Comment: your word will be padded with spaces or punctuation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function CheckForSit(inpt As String) As Long
    Dim examin As String, patrn As String

    examin = " " & LCase(inpt) & " "
    patrn = " sit "

    If InStr(examin, patrn) > 0 Then
        CheckForSit = 1
    Else
        CheckForSit = 0
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

This assumes the lack of punctuation like ***sit.*** or ***sit?***

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex as you want a word found not just a substring. This currently outputs the result in the adjacent right hand column.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub IsWordFound()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("E2:E3").Value
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 1))
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 2) = IsFound(arr(i, 1), "sit")
        Next i
       .Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub

Public Function IsFound(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal word As String) As Byte
    Dim  re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\b" & word & "\b"
        If .test(inputString) Then
           IsFound = 1
        Else
           IsFound = 0
        End If
    End With
End Function
```